# How to return an item value from localForage in a context of method?

Tags: javascript, promise, html-framework-7, localforage

I'm trying to return a value from a method, but all what it returns is "NaN" ("Not A Number"). So, the problem is that this method need to receive a value from a *localForage* promise and then return it as a regular method.

I've tried to use "async function" and "await", but it's definitely not an option because of Framework7 limitation I guess.

```
var app = new Framework7({
  ...
  methods: {
    getStorage: function (target) {
      return localForage.getItem(target).then(function (value) {
        console.log("getStorage: " + target + " is " + value);
        return value;
      });
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

The method returns "NaN" instead of an item value of localForage, although "console.log" returns an actual value.

Will be grateful for any help

EDIT: added a few lines of code

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
getStorage = function (target) {
  return localStorage.getItem(target).then(function (value) {
    console.log("getStorage: " + target + " is " + value);
    return value;
  });
};
```

I saw in this code wrong when calling localStorage

Comment: I appreciate your help, but firstly this is a "function" in a method and it's forced to be like this, not like a variable and not like an unnamed function.
And no, I'm not wrong with "localForage": https://localforage.github.io/localForage/

Comment: please do some research before answering question. when you hear a new term, even it sounds like a typo, do a google search. localStorage and localForage are different. well not that different, but two different things at least.